# Connect to remote database when deployed on Vercel

Tags: mysql, next.js, web-hosting, remote-access, vercel

In my NextJS Vercel app, I am unable to successfully connect to my remote MySQL database which is located on GoDaddy, after following [Vercel's official tutorial](https://vercel.com/guides/deploying-next-and-mysql-with-vercel).

I expect the api pages to return JSON data that resulted from the database query. Instead I am getting [image: Empty error object property of columns object in Firefox JSON page]

I tried changing the username, but for some reason, the 4 environment variables that I have - MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_DATABASE, MYSQL_HOST, and MYSQL_PASSWORD - never update on the live site! I changed in Production, Preview, and even Development, and they stay the same in the above link’s object.

Everything works fine on my `localhost` because my home IP address is whitelisted in cPanel. But Vercel has dynamic IPs so I can't do this on the live site. It also works fine if I host on GoDaddy, but I need to host on Vercel.

Here’s my source code for the db.js file which connects to the database

**lib/db.js**

```
const mysql = require('serverless-mysql');

const db = mysql({
    config: {
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
        user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    }
})

exports.query = async query => {
    try {
        const results = await db.query(query);
        await db.end();
        return results
    } catch (error) {
        return { 
            error
        }
    }
}
```

**pages/api/columns/index.js**

```
const db = require('../../../lib/db')
const escape = require('sql-template-strings')

/**
 * Queries the database to return the newspaper's columns
 * @param {IncomingMessage} _req The request object (unused)
 * @param {ServerResponse} res The response object
 */
module.exports = async (_req, res) => {
    const columns = await db.query(escape`SELECT * FROM columns ORDER BY id`);
    res.status(200).json({ columns })
}
```

I expect this result, which appears locally:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Connecting to a remote database only works with Cloud hosting (e.g. Microsoft Azure, AWS). Because I am using a Hosting service, this won't work.</s>

In **Remote MySQL**, whitelist `%.%.%.%`. Because Vercel's IPs are dynamic, this will allow a consistent connection between Vercel and the database. It is also a security risk, but I have a password protection.

Comment: I have a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75502931/470749