# How to securely connect to a database in Next.js app (using Prisma and MySQL) deployed to Vercel (serverless)

Tags: mysql, next.js, serverless, prisma, vercel

My MySQL database on DigitalOcean is locked down to only be accessible via local connection.

I'd strongly prefer to keep it secure like that (i.e. not to open it up).

I'm used to using SSH tunnels to connect to it (such as `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myusername@myhost`).

Now that I'm deploying a Next.js app (with Prisma) to Vercel, I'm trying to figure out the appropriate `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

How can I set the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable (or whatever other relevant setting) such that my Next.js backend is able to securely connect to my remote database that is only open to local connections?

I couldn't tell from [the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql#configuring-an-ssl-connection).

Comment: [Does this help you?](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/2098#discussioncomment-3400)

Comment: I hadn't seen that page. It does seem on-topic, but I still don't see the answer, so I asked again there. Thanks.

Comment: There is no url that allows you to do that. You have to open the tunnel and then connect, maybe other types of tunnels such as VPN would be more suitable for the case you are asking.

Comment: I'm flexible. It doesn't even need to be MySQL. It could be Postgres, for example. I just want a relational DB that is secure yet accessible by the Next.js serverless backend on Vercel. I haven't found anywhere how to do it (securely). If Vercel supports a VPN, I haven't found the docs. Thanks @FedericoSierra

Comment: I just found https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-allowlist-deployment-ip-address which seems to say that the level of security that I expected probably is impossible.